# Linked Lists : When adding a element why is current.Next pointing to the new Node, and why do we overwrite the Current Node

Tags: c#, data-structures, linked-list

I am a beginner to C# and I am picking it up by solving data structures case scenarios.  I need help visualizing what is happening in the following code snippet

```
public void AddAtLast(object data)
{
   Node newNode = new Node();
   newNode.Value = data;
   current.Next = newNode;
   current = newNode;
   Count++;
}
```

**What part I have understood**

I am aware that a new node is being added at the end of the linked list. Also, the new node is getting its value from the function argument.

**What I need help with**

I am particularly thinking why `current.Next` is pointing to `newNode`, shouldn't it point to NULL since my `newNode` will be placed at the end of the linked list and so it should point to NULL.

Also, why are we doing `current=newNode` ?

I understand why `count++` is present probably because that want to keep track of position at which the new element is added but correct me if my understanding is wrong with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So let's see what's happening line-by-line in the `AddAtLast(object data)` method of the [Linked List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) Class

1. `Node newNode = new Node();`

Create a new *Node*, this is the `AddAtLast` methods goal in life

2. `newNode.Value = data;`

Assign some data to the *Node*

3. `current.Next = newNode;`

Assign the `newNode` that was created to `Current`. This is the *Linked* part of a *Linked List*

4. `current = newNode;`

Overwrite `Current` (this must seem strange); I'll explain about this more later.

5. `Count++`

Increment the `Count` of the `Linked List`, Its nice to know the size of a list, without having to traverse all its elements. This is just a short hand way of always knowing the count.

---

**The first thing you have to remember**

Is in C# (and many other languages), objects/Classes are a [Reference Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). When you create `Current` (or any other object/class) you are doing 2 things.

1. Reserving a physical part of memory and filling it with your new Object
2. Creating a Reference (aka Address, aka Pointer) to that memory. Think of addresses just like a [Post-It-Note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-it_Note) to something that exists somewhere in your house.

When you overwrite a reference, you actually don't destroy the memory, just like if you scribbled out the address on a Post-It-Note and wrote something else. Your shoes still live in the cupboard. The only exception to this in .Net is if there are no more references left to you object/class the [Garbage Collector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/) (your mum) will come and clean it up and throw it away.

By calling `current = newNode;` it seems like we just lost overwrote it, and lost all references to that node (we were tracking last time), but we didn't.

---

**The second thing to remember**

The [Clever-Clogs](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/clever+clogs) who invented the *Linked List* knew we had to keep track of the items somehow, so they envisaged when a *Node* gets added, somewhere some other node needs to have a *Link* to it.

This is what this line of code (`current.Next = newNode`) was all about. Make sure its actually linked in the list. Yeah so we overwrote it, but we now know that while someone else is *Referencing* the *Node* its not going to be cleaned up. Additionally, if we want to find it again, all we have to do is find the first *Node* and traverse the linkages.

---

**Another way of thinking about it**

Think of `Current` as a bucket, in that bucket you have a *Node*, and on that *Node* is a piece of paper called next.

1. Someone hands you a new *Node*.
2. You studiously write the name of this new node (that someone gave us) on the *Node* you currently have in the bucket (the `Next/Link` Post-It-Note every node has)
3. You tip the bucket out on the floor and your put your new *Node* in the bucket.

But you have to remember, the *Node* you tipped out is still around somewhere (in-fact, there is likely another Node around with its name on it too, just like you wrote your new *Nodes* new name on **it**). Although, we cant access them easily, they are still there if we traverse the *Linkages*

In essence, this is how a *Linked List* works, its just a bunch of *Nodes* with other nodes names written on it.

We keep track of the list with tools like `Current/Temp`, and `First/Head` (Buckets) in the class that encapsulates this logic. Sometimes we have a `Count` to make it easier to know how many nodes we are tracking. Though truly, the most important part of a *Linked List* is the `First/Head` bucket. Without it we cannot traverse the list.

`Current/Temp` in your original method just makes us easy for us to find the last node, so you don't have to  traverse the list to find it

**Example**

[image]

Comment: But how did it traverse to the last ? I mean how are we certain that it has reached to end ?

Comment: Because `current` **is** the end.

Answer (score 1):

`current` is the candidate position for next `AddAtLast` operation, that is the end node of the linked list.

> I understand why count++ is present probably because that want to keep track of >position at which the new element is added but correct me if my understanding >is wrong with this .

For the linked list structure you showed here, while the `count` is used to keep track of the number of nodes, the `current` is to keep track of current to-be-add-at-last position(that is old last node in the linked list before adding newNode) to facilitate `AddAtLast` operation. After adding `newNode` at old `current` by `AddAtLast` method, your `current` will be moved and refer to updated last node(that is `newNode` which was added just now).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to keep track of current element as if you use a pointer in C for tail.
So, that you can have a reference to the end object reference. That's essentially a property of Type Node.